# Ember.js having more than one view per controller/model

Tags: ember.js

I have a controller and a model that get some data from the server.

I'm trying to initialize two views, one for editing and one for showing a list of items related to this data. For example, the model holds some search properties which the user may edit. After editing the search params I want to switch between the two views and display the refined search results.

I can't find any sample that does such switching.

I tried using Ember.ContainerView samples but all seems to be failing with nasty runtime errors.

Not sure that I have any relevant code sample :-(

Any help would be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a demo that toggles editing, nothing special but it simulates your use case I guess, have a look [here](http://jsbin.com/iwumuc/2/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks intuitivepixel, you really helped me nail this one.